# Keep PowerShell process alive without interrupting asynchronous event handlers

Tags: powershell

#### Summary

I'd like to know the best way to keep a PowerShell script running, without putting the main thread to sleep. Using `Start-Sleep` to keep a script alive has the side effect of blocking asycnhronous event handlers that are running on the same thread.

#### Example Code

Consider the following script, which demonstrates this blocking in action.

```
$Timer = [System.Timers.Timer]::new(500)
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $Timer -EventName Elapsed -Action { Write-Host -ForegroundColor Blue hi }
$Timer.Start()
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
```

When running this script, you'll see that the `Timer` is blocked from executing its handlers until the `Start-Sleep` command has completed. However, you'll also notice that the events are queued up in the background, and all fire in quick succession once the main thread is released.

Also, the script exits once the `Start-Sleep` command has finished running.

[image]

**Question**: How do I keep the PowerShell process / script running, without blocking event handlers?

Comment: Do...Until and test for an event when you do actually want to stop the script?

Answer (score 4):

I [asked a similar question](https://github.com/PowerShell/Polaris/issues/206) on the PowerShell Polaris repository on GitHub about a year ago. The answer for that specific module is to use the PowerShell `Wait-Event` command.

Using the `Wait-Event` command, with a random `-SourceIdentifier` will block further execution of the main thread, without blocking event handlers from executing.

```
$Timer = [System.Timers.Timer]::new(500)
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $Timer -EventName Elapsed -Action { Write-Host -ForegroundColor Blue hi }
$Timer.Start()
Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier SomeEventIdThatWillNeverExist
```

#### Conditional Termination

If the script has "completed" (*whatever that means to the author*), and the registered event handlers wish to terminate the script, they can do so.

The `-Action` event handler on the Timer, in this example, could optionally fire an event with the `SomeEventIdThatWillNeverExist` as the value for its `-SourceIdentifier` parameter, using the built-in `New-Event` command. Otherwise, an outside could forcefully terminate the process when appropriate.

```
$Timer = [System.Timers.Timer]::new(500)
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $Timer -EventName Elapsed -Action {
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor Blue hi
  if ((Get-Random -Maximum 100) -gt 95) {
    New-Event -SourceIdentifier SomeEventIdThatWillNeverExist
  }
}
$Timer.Start()
Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier SomeEventIdThatWillNeverExist
```

In an interactive PowerShell session, the Timer will continue to run after the script has completed execution. You would need to invoke the script using a separate PowerShell process (ie. `pwsh -File timer.ps1`).

[image]

At the moment, this is the best answer that I am aware of. However, if there's a better way of accomplishing this, I'm open to new answers.

Comment: The solution is a tad obscure, but if the intent is to simply _block_ the main thread while `-Action` script blocks associated with events are getting processed, that's probably the best solution. Note that even `Wait-Event` by itself will do in this case, because an `-Action` script block's output is reported via the `*-Job` cmdlets, not via the `*-Event` cmdlets, so no event should ever arrive (except if you also used _other_ events _without_ `-Action`, but then you'd have to process them in your main thread in order to take action based on them, precluding simply blocking the main thread).

Comment: Agreed, and your latter scenario is probably ripe for separation of concerns. Processing an event queue beyond the Timer, in this particular example, might call for a separate script (application).

Comment: Re termination: if you wrap the entire invocation in a `try` statement and execute the following in its `finally` clause, the event job will be removed and the timer disposed of (and thereby stopped), even if you terminate via Ctrl-C: `Get-Job | Remove-Job -Force; $Timer.Dispose()` (alternatively capture the output from `Register-ObjectEvent` in a variable and pipe that to `Remove-Job ...`).